# Stop deleting and downloading apps again to gain free access

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, ios7.1

I want to offer my app free for a period and then charge to continue using it. I understand that the way to do this is to force the user to buy an In-App product after the free period. However, if I simply record the date that the user starts using the app in the standardUserDefaults and use this to calculate when the user must buy the upgrade the user could simply delete the app when the time arrives (I assume the sandbox is also deleted) and download the app again for another free period.

First question. Is my reasoning so far correct?

Second question. Is there any way of accessing the date that an app is first downloaded?

Assuming the answers to these questions are Yes and No I have come up with the following solution.

Upon downloading the app the user is first forced to "buy" free an In-App product which then will have the date it was added to the transaction queue. This In-App product would then be downloaded for any subsequent download and I could use the date of this product as my reference date.

As I can find no reference to this problem or solutions I really wanted confirmation that this was a sound way to proceed or if there was another more standard way of dealing with the problem.

Thank you

Silas

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to limit you app for free for a limited period:

> **11.9** Apps containing content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected, except for specific approved content (e.g.
>   films, television programs, music, books)

If you want to risk it, you could save the date (encrypted) in keychain to make it more persistent.  Just so you know, user are able to access their keychain data if they iCloud keychain sharing and are on a Mac. So if they delete the correct key or rest there device your app will fall back to the free/trial mode.

Comment: But that seems exactly what whatsapp does?

Comment: Well not exactly, since that are asking money for their service. No for the app. And they are checking the free period time on there server not in the app.

Comment: Added a possibility on how you might do it, **but** be aware that is most likely going to be rejected for having a trial/free period.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem entirely consistent with:

> Communicate the value of your products to your users. Users want to
>   know exactly what they’re going to buy. Combine information from the
>   App Store, such as product prices and descriptions, with additional
>   data from your server or the app bundle, such as images or demos of
>   your products. Let users interact with a product in a limited way
>   before buying it. For example, a game that gives the user the option
>   to buy new race cars can allow users to run a test lap with the new
>   car. Likewise, a drawing app that lets the user buy additional brushes
>   can give users the chance to draw with the new brush on a small
>   scratch pad and see the difference between brushes. This kind of
>   design provides users an opportunity to experience the product and be
>   convinced they want to purchase it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html

One way of letting the user interact with a product feature in a limited way is to let them use it a few times before requiring that they pay to use the feature.